# Logging all Firefox HTTP Request Headers?

Tags: firefox, logging, headers

I'm using Ruby+Watir to request pages through Firefox.

I would like to record the headers and content of every http request made through the browser.

Would it be possible to configure a proxy solution to store this information, either in a file or pipe it into an application?

I'm running Ubuntu x64.

// Edit:

I would like to store the data in logs because I would like to view it later. Preferably, I am looking for a solution that runs quietly in the background and stores the headers/content in files.

Comment: Do you need to save it for later, or do you just want to view the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a Windows virtual machine or any other Windows physical machine, you can run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which should do exactly what you want.

After a brief look, I did find a program called [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which some people refer to as "Fiddler for Linux", but I have no experience using it.

Comment: Last time I installed Fiddler it installed something called FiddlerHook on FF.  Maybe that does what he's looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Proxy Sniffer](http://www.proxy-sniffer.com/download_en.html) - it has free edition.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) extension for this sort of thing.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear to support logging.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [Free HTTP Testing tool](http://soft-net.net/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Burp Proxy](http://www.portswigger.net/proxy/)

You can also try the Wireshark sniffer with appropriate filtering options. One general note on Windows self sniffing (sniffing on the loopback device) is that it is hard. But you use Ubuntu so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just Firefox you want, you can use the [Tamper Data addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) to view (and edit) these requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the firefox log to trace each http request.  It is not done by default.  Instructions are available at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_Logging)